# How do i bind multiple containers together?

Tags: codenameone

I have containers laid out as seen in the image below.

[image: Image for reference]

The page has two containers i.e. the first container contains Period ending:  and everything below it, and the second container is the one containing the periods and values.

My issue is on the second container. It has multiple containers inside it that have a BoxLayout.x() layout and each is scrollable along x-axis. So what i need help with is, i want to bind all these containers such that when i scroll along x-axis, they all scroll together.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Container.addScrollListener()` on each of them to bind a listener. When one moves you need to trigger the others. This is mockup code I didn't test but it should give you the idea. Notice the scrollingOwner variable is meant to block recursion but it might not be enough and might need to be more aggressive.

```
 for(cnt : contaienrs) {
     cnt.addScrollListener((scrollX, scrollY, oldscrollX, oldscrollY) -> {
         if(scrollingOwner != cnt) {
            return;
         } 
         scrollingOwner = cnt;
         for(cnt2 : containers) {
            if(cnt2 != scrollingOwner) {
                cnt2.scrollRectToVisible(scrollX, scrollY, scrollingOwner.getWidth(), scrollingOwner.getHeight(), cnt2);
            }
         }
         scrollingOwner = null;
     });
 }
```